# PHP хранение списка слов в файле

Tags: php, фильтрация

я делаю чат и хочу подключить фильтрацию нецензурной лексики, слова планирую сравнивать по словарю, подскажите как лучше всего хранить словарь, возможно массив?(Хранить в файле на сервере). Также как лучше всего проверять наличие слова в сообщение?(Мне нужны номера символов с первого по последний).

Comment: лучше хранить в бд. Там и индексы можно прикрутить и алгоритмы поиска присутствуют

Comment: @ArchDemon вряд ли он валидировать текст сообщений будет на стороне СУБД.  Как постоянное место хранения словаря БД пойдет, но его кэшировать надо в любом случае, и самый эффективный способ будет сделать вар-экспорт массива слов.

Comment: @teran, а я бы попробовал хранить в виде дерева, где в узлах будут буквы слова.  По памяти получается компактнее

Comment: @ArchDemon вы на структуру дерева памяти потратите больше, чем весь словарь весит.

Comment: Вот, именно поэтому и создал этот пост, у меня были варианты хранить в текстовом виде, в бд, просто массив парсить через ajax. Но я размышляю какой способ будет лучше...

Comment: Давайте, расскажу немного по подробнее, каждый раз когда пользователь отправляет сообщение оно сохраняется в бд и сохраняется уже зацензуренное, оно в любом случае отправляется на сервер, поэтому лучше хранить там. Но опять же я не вижу особого смысла создавать отдельную базу данных, насколько это целесообразно?

Comment: @teran, спорить не буду, готовых тестов у меня нет, но вот на хабре статья была, как человек паспортные данные ужимал. Он пользовался похожим способом. Но то было хранение в БД, и, возможно, данный опыт нельзя переносить в php. Однако, по дереву будет быстрее искать т.к. не придётся делать полное сканирование списка слов.

Comment: Автору же я желаю написать любую реализацию. Потому что сейчас он делит шкуру неубитого медведя. Тот или иной способ может сильно зависеть от необходимой скорости цензурирования.

Comment: @ArchDemon, хорошо у меня скорость не так важна, слов добавлю не больше 1000, а сообщение ограничено 200 символами, думаю это милисекунды исполнения, в любом случае спасибо Всем отвечающим)

Comment: @artemgh аякс то вам зачем? на бекенде делайте при отправке